# Destructuring nested objects in a Vue.js Pinia store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a things store with a state of:

```
{
  1: {
    name: 'Thing 1',
    type: 'Red'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Thing 2',
    type: 'Red'
  }
}
```

And I have a component for Things that gets an ID as a property.

```
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

import { useThingsStore } from '@/stores/things-store'

const
  props = defineProps({
    id: { type: String, required: true }
  }),
  thingStore = useThingsStore(),
  { removeThing } = thingStore,
  { things } = storeToRefs(useThingsStore())

</script>

<template>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{{ things[id].name || id }}</legend>

    <label>
      Name:
      <input v-model="things[id].name">
    </label>

    <label>
      Type:
      <input v-model="things[id].type">
    </label>

    <button type="button" @click="removeThing(id)">×</button>
  </fieldset>
</template>
```

How can I get the template to something like what's below while still preserving reactivity?

```
<template>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{{ name || id }}</legend>

    <label>
      Name:
      <input v-model="name">
    </label>

    <label>
      Type:
      <input v-model="type">
    </label>

    <button type="button" @click="removeThing(id)">×</button>
  </fieldset>
</template>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I've tried every combination of ref, toRef and toRefs that I can think of. The closest I could get it was the reactivity would work once on the page and then that was it.

Comment: storeToRefs can't work for nested keys, and toRefs isn't a good choice too because thingStore.things can be reassigned. You'd need to create a writable computed manually. You probably shouldn't do this at all, v-model like that is inconvenient to debug, could be updateName, etc actions

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `computed` property like this:

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
  <Things id="1" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Things from "./components/Things.vue"
</script>
```

```
// Things.vue
<template>
  <div>
  <label>
      Name:
      <input v-model="name">
  </label>
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue"
import { useStore } from '@/store/index.js'

const props = defineProps({ id: { type: String, required: true } })
const store = useStore()
const name = computed({
  get() {
    return store.things[props.id].name
  },
  set(name) {
    store.things[props.id].name = name
  }
})
</script>
```

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pinia-playground-forked-6294kh